# ibatis in/out parameter problem

Tags: java, ibatis, out-parameters

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
I have two procedures and two mappings for them. One works fine and another fails.
This one works fine:

```
    <parameterMap id="mapping-descriptions" class="java.util.Map">
        <parameter property="id" javaType="java.lang.Long" jdbcType="NUMBER" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="lang" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="shortDesc" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="OUT"/>
        <parameter property="fullDesc" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="OUT"/>
    </parameterMap>
<procedure id="get-description"
        parameterMap="mapping-descriptions">
        {call COM_DESCRIPTION_PKG.get_desc(?,?,?,?)}
</procedure>
```

And this one fails:

```
    <parameterMap id="mapping-description-modifiable" class="java.util.Map">
        <parameter property="id" javaType="java.lang.Long" jdbcType="NUMBER" mode="INOUT"/>
        <parameter property="lang" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="shortDesc" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="fullDesc" javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="modify" javaType="boolean" jdbcType="NUMBER" mode="IN"/>
    </parameterMap>
<procedure id="add-description"
        parameterMap="mapping-description-modifiable">
        {call COM_DESCRIPTION_PKG.add_desc(?,?,?,?,?)}
</procedure>
```

with this exception:

```
--- The error occurred while executing update procedure.  
--- Check the {call COM_DESCRIPTION_PKG.add_desc(?,?,?,?,?)}.  
--- Check the output parameters (register output parameters failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: -99999999
```

I can't understand what's wrong with second procedure and/or its mapping. Can it be some problem with "INOUT"?

Answer (score 5):

I've tried to pass a default value but it didn't help

---

It's working! Just changed jdbcType of id property to NUMERIC and it's worked! Unfortunately i don't need it anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

What value are you passing for the INOUT parameter ? 
My guess is that you need to provide a default value for it.